# Fancybox close button disapears when CSS and JS minified

Tags: javascript, .net, css, fancybox, minify

I have used Yahoo YUI Compressor for .net to minify my css and js and for some reason my fancybox close button is not appearing.  If I use the non-minified css and js files then it appears ok.  Any ideas why this might be happening?

Here's the relavant part of my build file

```
<ItemGroup>
      <CssFiles Include="../src/UserInterface/Content/css/styles.css" />
      <CssFiles Include="../src/UserInterface/Content/css/mcfcStyle.css" />
      <CssFiles Include="../src/UserInterface/Content/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"/>
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="../src/UserInterface/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">
        <CompressionType>None</CompressionType>
      </JavaScriptFiles >
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="../src/UserInterface/Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.latest.min.js">
        <CompressionType>None</CompressionType>
      </JavaScriptFiles >
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="../src/UserInterface/Scripts/jquery.countdown.min.js">
        <CompressionType>None</CompressionType>
      </JavaScriptFiles >
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="../src/UserInterface/Scripts/jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0-packed.js"/>
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="../src/UserInterface/Scripts/jquery.tipsy.js"/>
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="../src/UserInterface/Scripts/script.js"/>
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="../src/UserInterface/Content/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"/>
    </ItemGroup>
```

By the way we deploy today so I need a fix.

In styles.css I have

```
.close-history { display:block; width:30px; height:30px; background: url(../js/fancybox/fancy_close.png) no-repeat; text-indent: -999em; position:absolute; top:-15px; right:-15px; }
```

In jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css I have

```
.fancybox-ie6 #fancybox-close { background: transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_close.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
```

Comment: Is the close button in the DOM?  If not, we can isolate this to a JS issue, and if it is but isn't rendering properly, then it may be a CSS issue.

Comment: Is the build order the same as the inclusion order from your page?

Comment: These above files are in the exact same order as the files are included in non minified mode.

Comment: Beautify both files (normal and minified, and then diff them with program of your choice). You will see what gets munched, and will be able to fix it.

Comment: It seems like a path issue. I would set an absolute path for your js and css files. Also make sure that the fancybox sprite `fancybox.png` is under the same directory of the fancybox css files. If the problem is with IE check http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/8530478044b9f586

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9 times out of 10, it is a path issue to the img background.  Is the relative path for the background in the css still correct after minification?